# Filtering common rows into a Spark DataFrame based on matching values of a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to find corresponding rows between two DataFrames called `dfA` and `dfB`:

```
dfA.show()
+---+-----+-------+
| id| name|address|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1| AAAA|  Paris|
|  4| DDDD| Sydney|
+---+-----+-------+

dfB.show()
+---+-----+-------+
| id| name|address|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1| AAAA|  Paris|
|  2| BBBB|NewYork|
|  3| CCCC| London|
|  4| DDDD| Sydney|
+---+-----+-------+
```

I use a list of values constructed as follows:

```
val array = dfA
  .select("id")
  .map(r =>{r.getString(0)})
  .collect()

array Output:
1
2
```

In order to have the corresponding values between both DataFrames:

```
val dfFilter = dfB.filter(dfB.col("id").isInCollection(array))
  .select("id")

dfFilter.show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  4|
+---+
```

This code works correctly provided that one uses only one column named `id` used for the search.

My question is how to do this research of common rows using several columns (`id`, `name`, `address`) between `dfA` and `dfB`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a semi-join. Just put any number of columns in the `Seq` that you wish to use for filtering.

```
val result = dfA.join(dfB, Seq("id", "name", "address"), "left_semi")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ! Is there another way than make a join because in my case it is underperforming

Comment: You can broadcast `dfB` if it is small enough

Comment: What do you mean by underperforming? What's the scale of your data and the run time?